# MySQL из сайта на Android - возможно ли это?

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных

Могу ли я в своём Android-приложении брать данные из БД MySQl, расположенной на сервере?

Если да, то как?
Если нет, то какие мне тогда нужно учить ЯП для доступа к БД из моего приложения?

**Спасибо большое**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217835/can-an-android-app-connect-directly-to-an-online-mysql-database

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev, Спасибо!